# What's wrong with this apache2 site-config-file?

Tags: apache

I researched a lot on the Internet how to fix this file, unfortunately I'm not able to find the solution. My apache2-server is still not accessible via public ip so I'm asking here now. If I try to access the apache2-server over http it basically connects to my router-web-interface which shouldn't be the case. Connecting via https results in a timeout. If I delete the *:80 thingy and change the *:443 to *:80, it works for http. Actually I don't know the real reason so.. here's the file. I'd be glad if someone could fix this for me since I've running several services on it which I need every day.

Port-forwarding is configured correctly (it worked for over 1 year, but I changed something in this file and now it doesn't work anymore)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34140308/tmp_apache2.txt

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state it but I guess your server is behind NAT and you access this *:80 HTTP vhost using a different port number and your router's public IP. Say your router's public IP is 1.2.3.4, your server private address is 192.168.0.1 and you have port forwarding configured so that TCP traffic going to 1.2.3.4:8080 gets redirected to 192.168.0.1:80.

This is plain HTTP which your Apache receives on port 80 and applies the config for *:80 vhost. Your *:80 vhost contains a redirect rule that tells it to redirect all non HTTPS traffic to `https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1`. `%{HTTP_HOST}` in this case holds the name you used to in your web browser to access the page, for example, if you used the public IP of the server it holds '1.2.3.4'. So the redirect rule redirects you to `https://1.2.3.4/...` which is your router web interface.

If you haven't change port forwarding settings on your router than most likely you have recently added the redirect to the HTTP Vhost ro you removed a port number from the rewrite rule. In other words: the redirect should not be there, or the it should point you to something like `https://1.2.3.4:HTTPS_PORT/...` where the HTTPS_PORT is the port number on the public side that will take you to the TCP 443 on the local server.

Comment: I'm not using different ports for my site. http is on port 80 and https is on port 443. I recently noticed that my router somehow blocks port 80 and 443 since I updated it (is this even possible? it doesn't show an error message when configuring port forwarding). I edited the config file a few weeks ago, I tried to change it back. Basically it's working again if I access it via the local ip. If I want to access it via the public ip, I need to configure it like that: https://pu.bl.ic.ip:some_port which redirects to port 443 on my apache server, but if I use 443 for "some_port", it doesn't work

Comment: What is the brand of the router? Can you show us a screenshot of your forwarding settings?